# WPF validation custom trigger

Tags: wpf, validation

I have couple of bound TextBoxes with validation enabled.

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" />
  <Button Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
```

When view is opened i have these textboxes invalid by default because I have NotEmpty vlaidation on them.

I want validation to happen only at last moment, when i click Ok.
How can I trigger validation from code (Button`s Command)?

Comment: Can you show the code that how you are using `NotEmpty` Validation?

Comment: I use FluentValidation library. The thing is it is working ok but i need to find out how to trigger validation by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the validation explicitly by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` for your binding like this -

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1"
         Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2"
         Text="{Binding Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
<Button Click="Button_Click"/>
```

And in handler you have to explicitly update the source like this -

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    textBox2.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

Comment: Is there any MVVM friendly solutions?